# DCC plugin to SpamAssassin does not get loaded on Debian 9

Tags: debian, spamassassin

In spite of having this in `spamassassin -D` output the plugin does not seem loaded:

```
Feb  1 21:05:53.653 [7880] dbg: config: read file /usr/share/spamassassin/25_dcc.cf
```

I get this:

```
Feb  1 21:05:54.230 [7880] info: config: failed to parse line, skipping, in "/etc/spamassassin/local.cf": auto_whitelist_factor 0.05
Feb  1 21:05:54.232 [7880] info: config: failed to parse line, skipping, in "/etc/spamassassin/local.cf": dcc_path /usr/local/bin/dccproc
Feb  1 21:05:54.232 [7880] info: config: failed to parse line, skipping, in "/etc/spamassassin/local.cf": use_dcc 1
Feb  1 21:05:54.232 [7880] info: config: failed to parse line, skipping, in "/etc/spamassassin/local.cf": dcc_body_max 2
Feb  1 21:05:54.232 [7880] info: config: failed to parse line, skipping, in "/etc/spamassassin/local.cf": dcc_fuz1_max 2
Feb  1 21:05:54.232 [7880] info: config: failed to parse line, skipping, in "/etc/spamassassin/local.cf": dcc_fuz2_max 999999
Feb  1 21:05:54.232 [7880] info: config: failed to parse line, skipping, in "/etc/spamassassin/local.cf": dcc_home /var/dcc
```

Debian 9 x64, stock SA, DCC plugin installed in different ways (from CPAN, from DCC source distribution, etc).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

[Debian ManPages](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/spamassassin/Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::DCC.3pm.en.html)

[Decription](https://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.1.x/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Plugin_DCC.html)
[Home page](https://www.dcc-servers.net/dcc/)

Uncomment `loadplugin Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::DCC` in `/etc/spamassassin/v310.pre`

According DCC [recommendations](https://www.dcc-servers.net/dcc/firewall.html) we need to have port 6277 UDP opened on firewall

```
sudo ufw allow 6277/udp
```

How to install [Nice article](http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/add-dcc-distributed-checksum-clearing-houses-pyzor-and-razon-checks-in-spamassassin-on-debian-lenny-howto-improve-spamassassin-anti-spam-protection-on-debian-gnu-linux/)

Download
Get the latest version link from `https://www.dcc-servers.net/src/dcc/`

```
sudo -i
cd /tmp
wget 'https://www.dcc-servers.net/src/dcc/dcc.tar.Z'
tar xvzf dcc.tar.Z
cd dcc-1.3.163/ ## latest version on 2018-12-30
./configure && make && make install
```

DCC home folder is `/var/dcc`

insert in local.cf for Spamassassin

```
use_dcc 1
dcc_timeout 8
dcc_home /var/dcc/
dcc_path /usr/local/bin/dccproc
add_header all DCC _DCCB_: _DCCR_
```